# can access visdom server but no plot is shown

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, visdom

programmers.

I am using visdom to display loss plots when training deep learning models. I can access the visdom server in my locahost:8097. I also can see something posted to the server when I run a simple toy code which tries to display a plot.

However, all I see in the browser is just a blue screen. No plot is displayed on the website.

[Image of screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smrex.png)

What I tried:

1. looking at the server logs:

```
Checking for scripts.
It's Alive!
INFO:root:Application Started
INFO:root:Working directory: /home/dang/.visdom
You can navigate to http://localhost:8097
INFO:tornado.access:101 GET /vis_socket (127.0.0.1) 1.07ms
INFO:root:Opened visdom socket from ip: 127.0.0.1
ERROR:tornado.general:Could not open static file '/home/dang/anaconda3/envs/bci/lib/python3.11/site-packages/visdom/user/style.css'
...
INFO:tornado.access:200 GET /static/css/style.css?v=5992e699473eac51703490c400a846997177fd7c6fb92ba8fbe96db526c2df816716dfebbcd1957bce1b09890c83899e46a5100017ab20e06ca91796a31571bb (127.0.0.1) 6.57ms
INFO:tornado.access:200 GET /user/style.css (127.0.0.1) 5.81ms
INFO:tornado.access:200 GET /static/css/network.css?v=514a54ce7c32ff26a26532a6ac209729ea7f0a1ca05bdc60529925a75d487537286a804df37d75ea2aee6b4a6d80ce902ffb8bffc85f15cd33e1e3386cb40aad (127.0.0.1) 0.92ms
ERROR:tornado.general:Could not open static file '/home/dang/anaconda3/envs/bci/lib/python3.11/site-packages/visdom/user/style.css'
INFO:tornado.access:200 GET /favicon.png (127.0.0.1) 27.08ms
INFO:tornado.access:200 GET /static/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 (127.0.0.1) 0.59ms
INFO:tornado.access:101 GET /socket (127.0.0.1) 0.56ms
INFO:root:Opened new socket from ip: 127.0.0.1
INFO:tornado.access:200 POST /env/main (127.0.0.1) 0.66ms
INFO:tornado.access:200 POST /env/main (127.0.0.1) 0.42ms
```

2. close all ad-blockers in my browser.
3. use another browser.
4. use another script for plotting.

Here is my script:
First, I start visdom in the terminal.

```
visdom
```

Then, I run this code:

```py
from visdom import Visdom
import numpy as np

# Create a Visdom instance
viz = Visdom()

# Generate dummy data
x = np.arange(10)
y = np.random.rand(10)

# Create a line plot
viz.line(X=x, Y=y, opts=dict(title='Dummy Line Plot', xlabel='X', ylabel='Y'))
```

If anyone can help, thank you very much!

Or are there any recommondations on tools for visualization?